drive access (udisksctl mount) won't work after changing uid and gid
On Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, I have one additional disk (ext4.2) one user (user.1) can't access easily anymore (No problems with his /home folder).
I've changed the UID and GID of user.1 to eventually share some files on the ext4.2 drive with other computers.
(* following this page for instructions https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-correctly-change-the-uid-and-gid-of-a-user-group-in-linux/)
After that, user.1 can mount (Nautilus / sudo udisksctl) any additional drives but access nothing in Nautilus. He can create folders, mount drives manually and access files from /mnt/ext4.2 but I'm trying to understand what I've missed or flipped with udisks.
A newly created user.2 can mount and access additional drives.
Both users are in the same groups (except those of the same name as the user).

user.2 can access his own folder /media/user.2 in a shell,
user.1 can't without sudo.

Both users' folders got "drwxr-x---+ root root" permissions.
Does my system keeps the old UID/GID over the /media/user.1 folder somewhere? Is it something else?

Simple workaround : delete the /media/user.1 folder and mount the additional drive again. The folder will be recreated and drive will mount normally.
I think this is a kind of answer... maybe there were a trace somewhere.
